# How do I get django to execute a remote celery task? Seems to ignore BROKER_URL in settings.py

Tags: django, celery

I've got a django app that's trying to call a celery task that will eventually be executed on some remote hosts. The task codebase is completely separate to the django project, so I'm using `celery.execute.send_task` and calling it from a `post_delete` model signal. The code looks a bit like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def do_async_thing(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        celery.execute.send_task("tasks.do_my_thing", args=[instance.name])

signals.post_delete.connect(MyModel.do_async_thing, sender=MyModel)
```

I'm using the latest Django (1.6.1) and celery 3.1.7, so I understand that I don't need any extra module or app in my django project for it to be able to talk to celery. I've set `BROKER_URL` inside my `settings.py` to be the right url `amqp://user:password@host/vhost`.

When this method fires, I get a `Connection Refused` error. There's no indication on the celery broker that any connection was attempted - I guess it's not seeing the `BROKER_URL` configuration and is trying to connect to localhost.

How do I make this work? What extra configuration does `send_task` need to know where the broker is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I discovered the answer, and it was to do with not reading the tutorial (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) closely enough.

Specifically, I had the correct `celery.py` in place which I would have thought should have loaded the settings, but I'd missed the necessary changes to `__init__.py` in the django project, which wasn't hooking everything together.

My `celery.py` should be:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

app = Celery('mypoject')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

and the `__init__.py` should be simply:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Comment: just one comment: with this setting your command to run celery need to be 'celery -A myproject.celery_app worker'. I was missing the .celery_app, and wonder why the settings didn't get applied